# Modify the size of popup windows in IE9?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have a client that uses a web app extensively that utilizes popup windows to display search results. Her problem is that when popups get displayed, they are very small in size and she is forced to resize the window every time.

- I've tried resizing, closing IE9 and all tabs, and reopening.
- Restarting the computer multiple times.
- Upgrading from IE8 to IE9 did not seem to fix this issue either, so I have to believe a fresh install or repair will not fix this problem.
- I am aware of the setting in internet options that allows for popups to be created as new tabs, but she is not fond of that idea and prefers a new popup window.

So my question is, is there some setting that I am missing out on here that will allow me to set how large popup windows are? Hopefully there is a simple solution to this and I am just missing something.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the popup window is generally set in the code of the site that's creating the popup. There's nothing that you can do on the client side to change this behavior, other than making it into a tab.